# In elasticbeanstalk, can I ssh in and manually restart the (node) app?

Tags: bash, ssh, amazon-web-services

I want to `eb ssh` in, stop the node app (not the entire instance), make a debug change, and `npm start`.

When I `eb ssh` in I can inspect my files, and edit them. But I can't use the `npm` commands, and I can't seem to discover the node process using my bash-fu. In the aws cli docs I see only `eb stop` and `eb start` which restart the entire server (losing my changes I think its safe to assume).

Is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To modify the running code, edit the files in:

```
/var/app/current
```

Then, running:

```
sudo pkill -f node
```

will cause your node app to be restarted, with the latest code running.

Comment: There is not process for node is the app crashes initially. How does one go about starting it if there is no current process to `pkill`?

Answer (score 5):

Elastic Beanstalk uses upstart to manage its processes.

You can use initctl to restart the processes.

For example

```
initctl restart nodejs
```

Obviously you can start it with `start` instead of restart if it's not already running for some reason.

Similarly you can apply the same to any process managed by upstart. You can find the names of these processes using

```
initctl list
```

Answer (score 2):

See [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50142417/4064901) to a similar question in SO

The gist being, for a nodejs specific app, try

```
# to start the process
python /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action start-all
# to stop the process
sudo python /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action stop-all
```